# ORCfile storage implementation in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

does anybody know how to use ORCfiles input/output in Pig?
I found some kind of support for RCFiles in elephant-birds, but it seems ORC format is not supported... 
Could you please provide a sample of using Pig to access/store ORC files in Pig?

Answer (score 4):

Support for ORC Storage through Pig is not yet committed and under active development. Refer to Apache JIRA PIG-3558. Following this, you would be able to access ORC files via your Pig Script like this

```
load 'foo.orc' using OrcStorage();
...
store .. using OrcStorage('-c SNAPPY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a HCatalog table using HCat CLI stored as ORC.Then LOAD the relation in pig using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() or STORE using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer()

Comment: thanks, I will try it... unfortunately, I had nasty experience w/ HCatalog when it was not able to manage boolean between hive and pig

Comment: ok, just checked source code - HCatalog still doesn't support booleans